# How to restrict adding duplicate item in VB6

Tags: vb6, activereports, componentone

I have an application written in VB6.

This application contain a file with snippet containing a `foreach` loop. In this loop a method is adding controls to a section (section is a region in report).

I am trying to implement a functionality where:

when `theheader` is added in `headerSection`, `tt` will not add `theHeader` again, however this snippet is unable to do that. Where am I going wrong?

```
For Each thisColumn As Column In theColumns
  If thisColumn.Type = Column.ColumnType.Description Then
     AddDescriptionColumn(thisColumn, startColumnAt, headerTop)
  End If
 Private Sub AddDescriptionColumn(ByVal ColumnToAdd As Column, ByRef LeftPosition As Single, ByVal HeaderTop As Single)

  'Get report sections
  Dim headerSection As ActiveReports.Section = _theActiveReport.Sections(PageHeaderName)

  'Add column header text
  Dim theHeader As New ActiveReports.Label
  theHeader.Name = "lblDescription"
  theHeader.Text = ColumnToAdd.DisplayCaption
  theHeader.Font = ColumnToAdd.HeaderFont
  theHeader.Location = New PointF(LeftPosition, HeaderTop)
  theHeader.Size = New SizeF(columnWidth, _columnHeaderHeight)
  If TextHeight(ColumnToAdd.DisplayCaption, theHeader.Font, columnWidth) > _columnHeaderHeight Then
     theHeader.VerticalAlignment = ActiveReports.VerticalTextAlignment.Top
  Else
     theHeader.VerticalAlignment = ActiveReports.VerticalTextAlignment.Bottom
  End If
  theHeader.BackColor = Color.Transparent
  theHeader.MultiLine = True
  theHeader.WordWrap = True
  theHeader.Visible = True
  headerSection.Controls.Add(theHeader)
```

Comment: `Dim headerSection As ActiveReports.Section = _theActiveReport.Sections(PageHeaderName)` is invalid VB6 syntax. Is this VB.Net source?

Comment: This is VB.Net code not VB6 code. `SizeF`, `PointF` are .Net types. `For Each thisColumn As Column In theColumns` is VB.Net, it's not legal to use `As` inside `ForEach` in VB6. And as wqw said it's not legal to initialize variables on the `Dim` line in VB6

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
Private Sub AddDescriptionColumn(...
Dim bolFound as boolean=False

'Get report sections
Dim headerSection As ActiveReports.Section = _theActiveReport.Sections(PageHeaderName)

' Iterate through the list of controls. Set bolFound if control name already exists.
For Each control As ARControl In headerSection.Controls
    If control.Name="lblDescription" Then
      bolFound=True
      Exit For
    End If
Next

If bolFound=True Then
  'A control named lblDescription already exists in the headerSection
Else
  'Add column header text
  ...
End If
```